# Aligning multiple objects/joints for rigging

Tags: rigging, snapping

i just started learning blender, but am having trouble understanding how to combine multiple objects into mechanical joints.

Specifically, I would like to assemble a T-pose for a small robot from individual STL files to later use in animations via mechanical rigging. I've watched several multi-hour tutorials on rigging and aligning, but I don't seem to have understood how to assemble the various objects to create a T-pose.

My basic layout would look something like this:
[image]

I would really appreciate it if someone could give me a hint on how or where to start!

Comment: The T pose is the typical rest pose of a character mesh and armature. You show some pieces, first thing is that they don't seem to be assembled as they should (?), second thing is that we don't see the armature to which you'll rig your pieces. Maybe tell a bit more?

Comment: That image seems to be an "exploded view". Are you talking about moving the objects to their correct pivot points ready to be animated or actually rigging them for animation.

Comment: Thank you both, I should have made myself more clearer. As you've pointed out, the objects in my example aren't assembled and that's exactly what I'm after. I'm trying to learn how to bring each object into position (pivot points) to end up with a t pose.

My little robot project consists of over a hundred small pieces, all single stl files, and I was told that blender would be ideal to align them/bring them into pivot positions – however I struggle to grasp the workflow and when I use the snapping functionality or align them manually, the results are less than desirable.

Comment: To align the pieces you can use the 3D cursor and the origins (Shift S), but each case will be different, also sometimes it can be faster to align visually. At last, keep in mind that once you've parented to an armature, the axis that will be taken into account will be the bone head, not the piece origin. But maybe ask a more specific question?

Comment: It-s not going to be a simple process to learn be honest although once you've got the hang of it you can move things around accurately pretty quickly. You need to learn about setting the origin of an object to the required pivot point, setting the 3D cursor to that origin and then moving your other object to the 3D cursor position.